# No response from HTTP request in mongodb/node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I have this as a server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = require('./api/models/toDoListModel'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/Tododb'); 


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var routes = require('./api/routes/toDoListRoutes');
routes(app);

app.listen(port);
```

And when I use posman to post/get, I get no response from the server (on a correct key-value) although localhost:27017 is running and I created a Tododb db using Robo 3T. But when I don't enter any key/value in postman, I get a response.  Am I missing something? All addresses are correct.

Comment: `.createConnection()` does not actually "connect". You need to initiate the connection. See [Connections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to MongoDB with the mongoose.connect() method.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Tododb');
```

If you don't call 
`mongoose.connect()` then `mongoose.connection` doesn't contain an an open connection. You should be using the return value from your `mongo.createConnection()` call instead (that you've to saved into db var and use that object).

Comment: Thanks! Mongodb was prompting a deprecation warning and I removed the .connect command. My bad.